# Sequelize queries with node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to determine a better way for my query.  I have two tables, one is for recipes, and another is for reviews.  Currently, I have two separate queries to find the recipe, and then find the reviews associated with the recipe.  Is there a better way I could be doing this?

RecipeController

```
module.exports = {
viewRecipe: function(req, res) {
    var recipeId = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
    var recipeM = {};
    var reviewM = {};
    db.recipe.find({
        where: {
            id: recipeId
        }
    }).then(function(recipe) {
        recipeM = recipe.dataValues;
        recipeM.ingredients = recipe.ingredients.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(",");
        recipeM.instructions = recipe.instructions.split("\n");
    }, function (e) {
    });
    db.review.findAll({
        where: {
            recipeId: recipeId
        }
    }).then(function(review) {
        console.log(review);
        res.render('viewRecipe', { recipe: recipeM, review: review, categories: categoriesMain, title: recipeM.title });
    }, function(e) {

    });

},
```

Comment: I suppose `Sequelize.Promise` could help you group these two parallel queries and wait for them to finish with your final query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a relationship set up between a recipe and its reviews, I believe you can use Sequelize's include option as follows:

```
db.recipe
  .findById(req.params.id, {
    include: [{
      model: review
    }]
  })
  .then(function(recipe) {
     // your success code
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
     // you error code
  });
```

As far as I know, the include option works as a left join.  Also, this should perform better since only one query will be ran on the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are permitted to use ES6 generator, you can apply co.wrap from npm module [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co)

```
module.exports = {                                                                                                                        
viewRecipe: co.wrap(function*(req, res) {                                                                                                 
    var recipeId = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);                                                                                           
    var recipeM = {};                                                                                                                     
    var reviewM = {};                                                                                                                     
    var recipe = yield db.recipe.find({                                                                                                   
        where: {                                                                                                                          
            id: recipeId                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                                 
    });                                                                                                                                   

    recipeM = recipe.dataValues;                                                                                                          
    recipeM.ingredients = recipe.ingredients.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(",");                                                              
    recipeM.instructions = recipe.instructions.split("\n");                                                                               

    var review = yield db.review.findAll({                                                                                                
        where: {                                                                                                                          
            recipeId: recipeId                                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                                                 
    });                                                                                                                                   

    console.log(review);                                                                                                                  
    res.render('viewRecipe', { recipe: recipeM, review: review, categories: categoriesMain, title: recipeM.title });                      
}).catch(function(e){                                                                                                                     

}),
```